# Google Charts: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-visualization

I cannot seem to get google charts working with JSON data.
I get this error: **'Cannot read property '0' of undefined.'**
The JSON response DOES have a JSON content type set. I've looked around at similar questions but cannot seem to find any solution.

**Javascript:**

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(get_data);

function get_data() {
  $.getJSON('/api?data=graphs', function(json) {
    var status = json.status;
    render_chart(status);
  });
}

function render_chart(status) {
  var status_chart = new google.visualization.DataTable(status);
  var options_status_chart = {
    lineWidth: 0,
    areaOpacity: 0.5
  }
}
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{
  "status": {
     "cols": [{
        "type": "string",
        "label": "Date - Time",
        "id": "dt_metric"
     }, {
        "type": "number",
        "label": "Status",
        "id": "s_metric"
     }],
     "rows": [{
        "c": [{
           "v": "2016\/1\/5 - 09:30"
        }, {
           "v": 0
        }]
     }, {
        "c": [{
           "v": "2016\/1\/5 - 10:00"
        }, {
           "v": 1
            }]
         }]
    }
}
```

Comment: The code and JSON provided work fine. Are you sure you have the correct URL? What does `console.log(json);` give you?

Comment: Yeah I've used the console logs already and they return 'Object {cols: Array[2], rows: Array[97]}'. This is why I don't understand what's not working :$

Comment: when do you receive the error? where is the code to draw the chart?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your JSON response, a missing curly brace at the end of the file. That's why it's not being parsed as proper JSON.

Comment: Apologies, that is my mistake from when I wrote the question. I have now updated the question. I have checked my entire JSON response and it is valid. Thanks.

Comment: Your JSON looks google-chart compliant. I think you aren't accessing the json object though. Could you remove the call to render_chart() and put a console.log(Object.keys(json).length) instead ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a scope issue. For testing purposes, declare your dataTable as null global. In the get_data() function just add : status_chart = new google.visualization.DataTable(json.status) and remove the call to render_chart.

Comment: Sorry I'm slightly confused, if I do that and remove the call to render_chart then nothing will happen?

Comment: It's to check that you are able to construct your datatable correctly.

Comment: Yeah but I mean if I remove the call to get_data() function and don't have anything in the console, then nothing will happen?

Comment: Something will happen for sure I can guarantee you. If nothing stricto sensu happens, it means that your datatable object is within scope and that it is being constructed correctly, therefore, problem solved. If it isn't the case, you'll either get the 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined.' error message or some Google error message.

Comment: I did that and nothing changed, I still get the undefined error. Interestingly, I tested it on another computer and that got a slightly different error: 'Cannot read property 'left' of undefined.'